# What is the alternative of "approve" in evm on Solana?

Tags: solana, spl, evm, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I have several wallets in evm. I give their X token access to my main wallet by calling Contract(x).approve() function. Thus i can make operations with these wallets. Now i want to do same thing on solana with solana web3 library. However i cannot find any function that gives allowance to my main wallet. The X token on Solana uses solana token program.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you cannot approve tokens using the normal `@solana/web3.js` package, so you'll have to use the `@solana/spl-token` package in one of two ways:

- `approve` does it from the client (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/edec44180c3349abd77677acb2270a00121f2936/token/js/client/token.js#L905)
- `createApproveInstruction` creates the instruction which you must include in a `Transasction` and then send (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/edec44180c3349abd77677acb2270a00121f2936/token/js/client/token.js#L1570)